# looking for direction with basic grep function in R (incorporated into a function)

Tags: r, function

Help with the following function. I am trying to create a function that will take values (from '`years`')  and run a simple grep on a `data.frame(searches)`.

The `data.frame(searches)` looks like;

```
> data.table(searches)[53:58]
         date hits    keyword          geo gprop   category
1: 2014-01-05   34 Price world             web        0
2: 2014-01-12   25 Price world             web        0
3: 2014-01-19   44 Price world             web        0
4: 2014-01-26   30 Price world             web        0
5: 2014-02-02   31 Price world             web        0
6: 2014-02-09   29 Price world             web        0
```

I am trying to extract each year, 2013, 2014, 2015 etc. at the moment using the grep function and save just the columns from the above data.frame "`date`" and "`hits`".

The code I currently have is;

```
years <- c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")


func_src <- for(i in ncol(1:5)){

  func_src[i] <- searches[grep(years(ncol[1:5]), searches$date),]
  print(func_src[i])
}
```

This returns a NULL value.

The final output I am hoping to obtain would have something like

```
colnames <- date hits1 hits2 hits3 hits4
```

(I am tidying the data based on date and not keyword as the keyword can change based on previous inputs, i.e. "`sell world`" and the date `2014, 2015, 2016` does not change)

EDIT: For clarification I paste in all the code and add in further comments.

The following code should get you to where I am at (it is just test data/var names so the number of `hits = 0` does not matter).

```
library(gtrendsR)

Variable_names <- c("VAR1") 

keywords <- c("US news", "", "Canada News", "US Car news", "Canada Car news")

trends <- apply(expand.grid(Variable_names, keywords), 1, paste, collapse=" ")
trends

searches <- gtrends(trends)$interest_over_time
searches <- searches[-c(1:4), ]


years <- c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")
```

After running this code, I hope to apply a function which will split across different years, 2013, 2014, 2015 etc. I have each keyword from 2013:2017 and I am only interested in keeping the date column and hits column. so;

I am trying to create a data.frame to have a date column, and then split on each row once we have reached the end of 2017 (as thats when a new keyword would come into play).

Ultimately I am trying to acheive

```
date hits1 hits2 hits3 hits4
```

each hits column would also correspond to each "keyword" in the keywords dataframe (but I am trying to split on year and not keyword)

hope this makes what I am trying to do a little clearer.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do after you pull year out? can you provide an example table of what it will look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not define a function, and, as written, it should not run. `ncol` is not  a defined variable, and yet you subset it (`ncol[1:5]`). See some example code below which is syntatically valid and will iteratively search for the years listed:

```
years <- c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017")
## Define a list to store the results
year_results <- list()
## A simple function which "greps" for the year and returns all results
func_src <- function(year) {
    searches[grep(year, searches$date), ]
}
## You can simply iterate through the vector "years"
for (year in years) {
    ## Store the result with the year as a name
    year_results[[year]]  <- func_src(year)    
}
print(year_results)
```

Alternatively you can use the `lapply` function, which will iterate over the years and store the result in a list:

```
lapply(years, func_src)
```

And if you want a named list:

```
setNames(lapply(years, func_src), years)
```

Comment: Thanks for your imput! I really appeciate it, it does not give me exactly what I am after. If you can give me 5 minutes I will put in all my code in the original question, so it can truely be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking this!

you can use the `lubridate` package to pull the year out. This is contained in `tidyverse` which is a medley of great tidying packages.

```
library(tidyverse)

searches_new <- searches %>%
    mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
    select(year, date, hits)
```

That will create a new column with just the year. I'm not sure what final output you want without more clarification. But I think you'll just want to either do some `group_by` or utilize `spread`